# SET Parent page (aspx) label text from User Control (ascx) using JavaScript and without PostBack()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, postback

I have a requirements to Change ASPX labelText in a User Control (ASCX) Using JavaScript and without postback or partial postback (Update Panel).

Please suggest how to implement this ? Thanks

//EDIT

**ASCX markup**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    function Show(text) {
        Popup.innerHTML = text;
        x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + 50;
        y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + 20;
        Popup.style.display = "block";
        Popup.style.left = x - Popup.scrollWidth + "px";
        Popup.style.top = y + "px";
    }

    function Hide() {
        Popup.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SaveTargetSign(id) {
        // Here i want to Access Parent Page Label and Set value.
    }
</script>

<table id="table1" width="970px" runat="server" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: solid 1px #D2B48C;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="tableSignature" width="975px" runat="server" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: solid 0px #D2B48C; background-color: ">
                <tr id="rowStatic" runat="server">
                    <td id="TD1" valign="top" style="width: 165px; border-bottom: solid 1px #D2B48C">
                        <div>
                            <div class="gridview">
                                <div class="outerSVSParent">
                                    <div class="scroll">
                                        <table class="gridtable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="width: 100%;
                                                border-collapse: collapse;">
                                            <tr class="header" style="height: 20px;">
                                                <td scope="col" id="lblDiv" runat="server">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblParentTitle" runat="server" Text="Title"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align: center">

                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSignId1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <uc1:ImageControl id="imageCtrl" runat="server" ShowActionButton="False" Height="80px" Width="100px" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr></tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                        <%--                        <div>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlTargetSign" runat="server" Height="16px" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTargetSign" runat="server" Text="Target Sign" TextAlign="Right" BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" BorderColor="#0066FF" BorderStyle="None" />
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </div>--%>

                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #D2B48C;">
                        <div style="height: 116px; overflow: scroll; padding-right: 20px;" id="tblDiv" runat="server">
                            <%--  <unisign:unisigngridview id="GridviewChild" autopostback="false" isnestedsvsgridview="True" pagesize="2" allowpaging="true" --%>
                                <UniSign:UniSignGridView ID="GridviewChild" AutoPostback="false" IsNestedSVSGridView="True" Width="805px" AllowSorting="true" runat="server">
                                </UniSign:UniSignGridView>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <%--  <unisign:unisigngridview id="GridviewChild" autopostback="false" isnestedsvsgridview="True" pagesize="2" allowpaging="true" --%>
                <div id="Popup" class="transparent" style="z-index: 200; width: auto; height: auto">
                </div>

                <asp:HiddenField ID="HFSVCurrentSelectedindex" Value="-1" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HFTargetSign" Value="0" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Server Side code to Trigger JavaScript**

```
  Dim scriptStatic = String.Format("javascript:return SaveTargetSign('{0}');", ststicId)
  rowStatic.Attributes.Add("onclick", scriptStatic)
```

**Parent Page Label Markup**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTSV" runat="server" BackColor="#F4F4F4" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#666666"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: If that label has an ID then either using [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) you can change the label text.

Comment: Hi Suprabhat, thanks for your reply. possible to share template of JavaScript ? i am a windows guy and new to Web and JS.

Comment: Just navigate to those two link shared above in my previous comment.

Comment: Suprabhat, it's getting value within the same page. But i want to Set label value of PARENT page from USER CONTROL JavaScript

Comment: How are you planning to change the label text? Is there a click event to perform this action?

Comment: When i click on  HtmlTableRow in User Control, it triggers JavaScript Function in ASCX. In that JavaScript function, i want to change the label text of parent page.

Comment: Can you share mark up for User Control and Master page (only the label part).

Comment: Shared, please check my updated question

Comment: See if this work for you `document.getElementById('<%= lblTSV.ClientID%>').textContent = 'Loreum Ipsum';`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still no luck,

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'lblTSV' is not declared.

Source Error:

 

Line 45:     function SaveTargetSign(id) {
Line 46: 
Line 47:     document.getElementById('<%= lblTSV.ClientID%>').textContent = 'Loreum Ipsum'; 
Line 48:         
Line 49:     //PageMethods.UpdateTargetSign(id, OnSuccess, onFailure);

Comment: My bad. It skipped from my mind that you are using user-control. I have posted an answer try that one instead.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a example how to talk clientside to any control you can use

```
document.getElementById('<%=Label.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "Tekst";
```

The controls gets a different name on clientside thats why you need to use the `document.getElementById`.

To achieve what you want you can use the below call to javascript from serverside. Use instead of Page.User.Identity.Name the text you want to display

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "changeLabelText", string.Format("changeLabelText('{0}');", Page.User.Identity.Name), true);
```

Which will execute the called script changeLabelText(labelText) on clientside and pass the identity name in this case.

```
function changeLabelText(labelText){
   document.getElementById('<%=LBLProjectsHeader.ClientID%>').innerHTML = labelText;
}
```

Hope the example gives you a idea of what you can do if you wanna straight on load of your page change the text on the label.

**Edit** some controls can be accessed with .value instead of .innerHTML